# Vagrantfile merge/append parameters

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I want to allow appending of parameters to `config.vm.synced_folder`. I want users to append additional parameters to this config.

I have so far:

```
append_params = 'x: false, y: false'
config.vm.synced_folder x['folder'], "/var/www", create: true, type: "nfs", append_params
```

If I remove `, append_params` it works. But with it, it fails with error:

```
There is a syntax error in the following Vagrantfile. The syntax error
message is reproduced below for convenience:
D:/x/Vagrantfile:32: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
```

How can I append additional parameters on request to `config.vm.synced_folder`?

Comment: make `append_params` a `Hash` e.g. `append_params = {x: false, y: false}` and then `**append_params` on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found the solution that works in my case as I have some `config.yml` with parameters that get parsed inside Vagrantfile

```
# config.yml
append_params:
    :someVar: false
    :fsnotify: true

# Vagrantfile
if File.file?("config.yml")
    parameters = YAML.load_file 'config.yml'
else
    parameters = {}
end
...
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    ...
    config.vm.synced_folder parameters['synced_folder'], "/var/www",  parameters['append_params'].merge({create: true, type: "nfs"})
```